# Pass variable argument arrays / collections to a function pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, c

How can I do variable arguments and args in C++?
A big problem is that C++ enforces type while python doesn't I think

If possible, I would like to have a macro that works in C as well.

So in python what I want to do is:

```
def f(*args):
    return sum(args)

def test_f(func,args):
    arr = []
    for y in args:
       arr.append(func(y,args))
    return arr

def main():
    test_f(f,[(range(1,x),range(2,x)) for x in range(10,100)])
```

I want to test a function with a varying parameter, or more generally a dynamic number of parameters that vary, sort of like Manipulate in Mathematica / but with a variable number of arguments if possible.

Thanks,

Comment: Two ways: variadic functions or variadic templates, prefer the latter.

Comment: If these arguments all should have the same type, you can just pass a `vector`

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz that would mean making a copy of all of them (or pointers to all of them), a bit wasteful.

Comment: @SethCarnegie You can always use a const reference, you know. I've left details on passing the vector out, because it depends on the actual function usage.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz even if you pass the vector by reference, you have to make copies of the objects to put them into the vector.

Comment: Please note that if you find yourself needing a variable number of arguments to a function, it most likely means that your program design is flawed somehow. Step back, think twice about what problem you are trying to solve. Ask an experienced programmer how they would solve the problem.

Comment: @Lundin this is for benchmarking a function - not any sort of production.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf All the more reason to keep it slim. I have no idea how compilers optimize variadic functions, but it wouldn't surprise me if they get more trouble inlining them into something deterministic.

Comment: @Lundin so how can I benchmark a function func, with an array of inputs and then times for the func that it runs. so for example testing addition of a giant array for 100 different array sizes.

Comment: Why would that be different from any other benchmark test? Start a timer before the function is called. Check the timer once the function is done. And that's it.

Comment: ...... no I mean doing that for any function / array for a few hundred thousand different arrays.